# JHipster : Custome pagination with post method and parameter

Tags: angularjs, jhipster

I generated one application using JHipster V3. I am trying to modify the search functionality and adding some kind of filter where user select some filter and hit search button and my angular search controller will make a POST call to my API.I did modification on server side to support filter search and return data.

Now I want to modify pagination link so that they also make a POST call with selected filter data instead of GET.

I did some investigation and found that when user click on link call goes to 'ui-bootstrap-tpls.min.js' [selectPage] function.

I dont want to make any changes on this js as it is global and will work for other UI screen.

Is there any better approach to implement such requirements?